# Design pattern for context menu provider

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, contextmenu

I need to implement context menu provider that getting information and supply context menu.
I have a lot of entities type and each entity have it's own options.

The options are by condition of type and instance. 
I'm using WPF, winform and other UI technologies and I need something generic that will let me to use it for each one of the technologies.

Is there some kind of design pattern that I can use?

Comment: It was not clear , if your question is how you can render the menu option then look at the Composition design pattern (where tree related hierarchy can be achieved) . If that's is not your need may be a picture or better explanation would help

Answer (score 0):

The [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) fits for your case. Each menu item will be associated with a command object, so when use click the menu item, that command will be triggered.

the code will like this;

```
public interface ICommand
{
    doSomeThing();
}

public class CommandA: ICommand
{}

public class CommandB: ICommand
{}

public class ContextMenuA
{
    ContextMenuA(ICommand a)
    {
        c= a;// a is an instance of CommandA 
    }
    private ICommand c;

    void OnClick()
    {
        if (c)
            c.doSomeThing(): 
    }

}
```

The code just show a general idea, not the real implementation. Please read [this:Understanding and Implementing Command Pattern in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339390/Understanding-and-Implementing-Command-Pattern-in)